# YUI custom event default function not executing

Tags: javascript, events, yui

Why does the default function for my event not execute when I specify it with `defaultFn`?

```
var node = Y.one(".foo");

node.publish("myEvent", {
    defaultFn: function () {
        //I don't understand why this doesn't execute
        //I expect it to execute after my on listener
        //and before my after listener
        Y.log("In default function");
    }
});

node.before("myEvent", function () {
    Y.log("In before listener");
 });
node.on("myEvent", function () {
    Y.log("In on listener");
});
node.after("myEvent", function () {
   Y.log("In after listener");
});

node.fire("myEvent");
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/steaks/rUacD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsfiddle shows you are loading only `node`.  To have events, you have to load one of the event modules.  As it happens, your code fails at the call to `publish`, the first method that event provides that it finds.

In general, check the API docs for the methods that fail and see which module provides them ('Inherited from' right below the heading for the method) and make sure you have the corresponding module loaded.

--
Updated according to newer JSFiddle:

Add `emitFacade: true` to the configuration of the published event.   YUI does this automatically for classes inheriting from `Base` but not for others.  For `Node` instances, you have to add that option explicitly.

Comment: I do have events.  That's why I can fire and listen to events.  It still doesn't work when I add `event-custom`: http://jsfiddle.net/steaks/rUacD/4/

Comment: Now you do, in version 4, there wasn't any events in the jsfiddle you first showed.

Comment: You'll find that version 1 is identical to version 4.  I was trying to load event modules per your suggestion.  Then I reverted my changes when I didn't find a solution.

Comment: In response to your edit.  I had tried setting emitFacade to true.  No dice.  The documentation about default functions also suggest that defaultFn is not dependent on emotFacade.

Comment: It doesn't?  Then perhaps I missread the first paragraph here:
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event-custom/index.html#facade

Comment: I read over the paragraph you referenced.  You're absolutely correct!  However, I still don't understand why http://jsfiddle.net/steaks/rUacD/6/ doesn't execute the default function.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  Here is a working JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/steaks/rUacD/11/

Comment: Great!  A further improvement: you can do away with the check on `domready` by placing your `<script>` tag at the bottom of the `<body>`.  That ensures that the script won't even be reached until the dom is ready.